# Does the limit exist for $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+x}}$?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+x}}\le \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2x^3}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\cdot2}$$

So the limit of $\displaystyle\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+x}}$ is finite?

Comment: yes the limit exists, use the rules of L'Hospital

Comment: You have correctly computed the limit, and yes, it is finite.. Replacing $\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+x}$ by $\sqrt{2x^3}$ was perhaps too informal.

Comment: divide by x^(3/2) top and bottom, meaning that x^3 divides into the inside of the square root - you'll then find that terms inside the square root are either constants or tend to zero, on the top arctan tends to pi/2 - you should end up with pi / (2 root 2)

Comment: oh yeah you pretty much did that, all you needed to do more formally was multiply by (1 / x^ (3/2)) / (1 / x ^ (3/2)) and cancel x^3/2 on the top and divide by x^3 inside the sqrt - giving sqrt(2 + 4/x + 1/x^2) as the denominator - the terms divided by x can then be cancelled as tending to zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2+4\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\cdot2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use equivalents:

- $\arctan x\sim_{+\infty}\dfrac\pi 2$,
- $\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+}x\sim_{+\infty}\sqrt{2x^3}$,

hence $\; \dfrac{x^{\tfrac{3}{2}}\cdot \arctan(x)}{\sqrt{2x^3+4x^2+x}}\sim_{+\infty}\dfrac{\pi x^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\mathstrut 2} x^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}=\dfrac{\pi\sqrt{\mathstrut2}}4$.